# Extension of formal power series is Galois

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}((t))$ be the field of formal power series in 1 variable $t$ over $\mathbb{C}$. For
every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\mathbb{C}((t^{1/n}))$ be the field of formal power series in $t$.

 I need to show that the extension $\mathbb{C}((t^{1/n}))/\mathbb{C}((t))$ is Galois. I am not sure how prove that it is $\mathbb{C}((t^{1/n}))$ is the splitting field of some separable polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}((t))$. Can such a polynomial be written specifically?

 Also, I would like to show that sending $t^{1/n} \rightarrow \xi_n t^{1/n}$ generates $Gal(\mathbb{C}((t^{1/n}))/\mathbb{C}((t)))$, so the Galois group is cyclic. Here $\xi_n$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

Comment: Note that $(t^{1/n})^n-t=0$.

Comment: So I consider the polynomial $p(x)=x^n-t$. Can I prove by induction that $\mathbb{C}((t^{1/n}))$ is the splitting field of $p(x)$?

Comment: We have $p(x)=x^n-t=(x-t^{1/n})(x^{n-1}+t^{1/n}x^{n-2}+ \dots + t^\frac{n-1}{n})$, which is not separable.

Comment: $t^{1/n}$ already generates $\mathbb{C}((t^{1/n}))$ as extension of $\mathbb{C}(t)$ and it also contains all roots of $x^n-t$, so it's the splitting field thereof. I don't understand the point of your second remark, $x^n-t$ is certainly separable.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand it. But how do I show the Galois group is generated by $t^{1/n} \rightarrow \xi_n t^{1/n}$? I can certainly see this is an automorphism of the field extension.

Comment: First of all, convince yourself that $x^n-t$ is irreducible. Then you know that automorphisms of this extension are in one-to-one correspondence with roots of $x^n-t$, but you know those.